# Unable to use string-based methods on a string property inside an Azure storage table query lambda

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

While querying an Azure storage table I get an exception.

Here is my query:

```
tableClient.QueryAsync<Resource>(resource => resource.PartitionKey == projectId.ToString()
            && String.Equals(resource.FullName, fullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

`resource.FullName` and `fullName` are both of type `string`.

But this incurs the exception...

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' (Parameter 'method')

And similarly, if I add an additional condition (before the `String.Equals`)...

```
&& !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resource.FullName)
```

... this incurs the exception...

> Method IsNullOrWhiteSpace not supported.

If I change the string comparison to...

```
resource.FullName.ToLower() == fullName.ToLower()
```

... then I'm told that `ToLower` is not supported.

What's going on here? Why can't I call `String.Equals` or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` on a property which is of type `string`? Am I misunderstanding something, and `resource.FullName` is actually not a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below suggestions and check if that helps.

1. Please check by updating `String.Equals` to [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-8.0)?
2. And instead of using ToLower() method, you can try to use `String.Compare` method with [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-7.0) option to achieve case-insensitive comparison:

```
tableClient.QueryAsync<Resource>(resource => 
    resource.PartitionKey == projectId.ToString() &&
    String.Compare(resource.FullName, fullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

3. You can also use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method along with [String.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-8.0) method:

```
tableClient.QueryAsync<Resource>(resource => 
    resource.PartitionKey == projectId.ToString() &&
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(resource.FullName) &&
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(resource.FullName.Trim()));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works. So Azure Table Storage has implemented `String.Compare` but not `String.Equals`? And it implements `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but not `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`? Is there a list of these methods as implemented by Azure Table Storage?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK tries to convert your LINQ-ish statement to a query that can be handled by the Azure Table Storage resource to return the appropriate items. The methods you try to call in it either can't be converted because the SDK has not implemented them. Either because the SDK misses he implementation or because the Azure Table Storage does not support similar methods in its queries.

For your scenario it is because Azure Table Storage does not support case insensitive queries. So you'll either need to change your data to always be lower or uppercase. Or retrieve the items and filter the items locally.